# подскажите как сделать insertRows в моей ситуации?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Слушайте столкнулся с такой проблемой! У меня три массива , для каждого массива свой раздел в общем сегмент контроль происходит. Я вот для каждого массива вот так назначил массив. Вот мой код.Подскажите что брать за массив?

```
   var soccerString = [Soccer]()
   var basketString = [Basketball]()
   var tennisString = [Tennis]()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var returnSport = 0
        switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0 :

            returnSport = soccerString.count
            break
        case 1 :
            returnSport = basketString.count
            break
        case 2 :
            returnSport = tennisString.count
            break
        default :
            break
        }

        return returnSport

    }
```

Я брал создавал функцию и в ней писал

```
soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at : 0)
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Но изменения не происходили.

Comment: Сделайте лучше единый объект, в котором будет enum для типа и массив для значений. И с ним работайте.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны производить вставку/удаление ячеек в таблицу между этими методами:

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 // Вставляем новые ячейки
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Пример:

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: yourArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Но я уже  решил этот вопрос.По другому действие пошло